# Limit of convergent series equal zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra

> Show that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent then
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n k a_k=0
> $$

If we let the limit of series be $A$ then it can be shown $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_1+\dots + a_n)/n=A$ as well. But how to deal with the term $ka_k$?

Comment: This is false: Suppose $a_n=1$ for all $n$ (thus $a_n$ converges to $1$). Then $\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Hence $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n(n+1)}{2n}=\infty$. Or did you mean that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is a convergent series?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding I meant precisely the latter

Comment: and since the last term converges, the desired result follows automatically by comparison test?

Comment: Oh I know the series converges but how to show the limit equals to zero? isit simply because of the denominator n?

Comment: Whoops, ignore that comment. I'm not sure how to show this, but I'm not very skilled at this either. Maybe this requires a bit more than basic inequalities.

Comment: I have an idea, but it will take some time to write down.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\to A$ then, by [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts),
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} ka_k=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(A_k-A_{k-1})=\sum_{k=1}^{n} kA_k-\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k-1)A_{k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{k-1}=nA_n-\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{k-1}$$
Hence, by the [Stolz-Cesaro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem),
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} ka_k=\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n
-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{k-1}}{n}=
A-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{A_n}{(n+1)-n}=A-A=0.$$

Comment: @Homaniac Any further doubt?

Comment: How does the second equality work?

Comment: @Homaniac See my edited answer. Any further doubt?

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n}a_k=0$. So choose $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists an $M$ such that $|a_k|<M$ for all $k$. We can take an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ large enough such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor}\frac{\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor}{N}M<\varepsilon$ and $\sum_{k=\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor+1}\frac{k}{N}a_k<\varepsilon$. (Why does such an $N$ exist?)

Now let $n\geq N$, then $$|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n}a_k|=|\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor}\frac{k}{n}a_k+\sum_{k=\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor+1}^n\frac{k}{n}a_k|\leq |\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor}\frac{k}{n}a_k|+|\sum_{k=\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor+1}^n\frac{k}{n}a_k|.$$

Clearly $|\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor}\frac{k}{n}a_k|\leq |\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor}\frac{\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor}{N}M|$ and $|\sum_{k=\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor+1}^n\frac{k}{n}a_k|<|\sum_{k=\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor+1}^na_k|$.

Putting everything together yields the answer.

Comment: I wrote this down quickly, I hope it's clear. The idea is to split the sum into two parts. In the first one I can control the factor $\frac{k}{n}$ (make it really small) and in the second one I use the tail of the original series.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I will need a lot of time to digest this..lol

Comment: You need an increasing $L$ to make the tail small. But $L$ needs to increase slowly, to control the first sum. I propose to use $L=\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor.$

Comment: Absolutely right, I messed up the orders badly. The idea is usable though. I'll fix it later as I have little time now.

Comment: I edited my answer. It should be clear why such an $N$ exists, if not, you can always ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Is is just an application of Kronercker's Lemma 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma

[image]

By simple choosing $b_n=n$, you can get what you want.